# Compute the size in [bytes] of ImageData Object

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, byte

Code:

```
// Create a new canvas
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Get drawing context
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Get image data
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

How to compute the size of imageData object in bytes?

Answer (score 2):

imageData.data has a type of [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8ClampedArray) wich is 1 byle long .

So : `imageData.data.length` will give you the size in bytes  which should be equal to `canvas.width * canvas.height * 4` .
You multiply width and height by 4 because each pixel stores 4 bytes, RGBA .

Comment: i got 307200 bytes ==> this value incredible

Comment: @MoathHowari : which value would you expect ? Don't forget that jpeg are compressed, and that a 10X or more compression ratio is easily reached with little artifacts.

Comment: @GameAlchemist but if i convert the canvas into image and saved it i don't get this large size explain it

Comment: It depends on how one would save the image , jpeg and gif compression will give different results . The value you get is raw image data .

Comment: Which format / quality do you use ? jpeg will do nice on photo when png will do nice with vector/cartoon graphics. As for the raw data size : the size taken in the video card memory to store the image -in a regular case- , Alexander's answer is just right : 4*width*height. In fact with hidpi devices, a *Canvas* element will use devicePixelRatio*context.backingStoreRatio*4*canvas.width*canvas.height, but that's another story... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/

Comment: @GameAlchemist still not believing length theory.

Comment: @MoathHowari.  The calculation is correct: canvas.width*canvas.height*4.  BTW, that's just the imageData.data array. The imageData object has other small-sized properties also...

Comment: No disrespect here, but your answer is funny :-) Let me explain shortly how a huge space can be saved for png : png uses run-length-encoding (RLE) meaning that when, say, 20 pixels have the same color, the encoding will be : repeat 20 : repeated color. Which takes 5 bytes instead of the 80 bytes of the rgba data !!! . A cartoon image will have such high ratio. Jpg is quite hard to explain (unless you know about FFT), but bottom line is this : the common image file standards do a veeery good job at reducing the image size. Rather a good news !! :-)